# How can we prove $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(m+k+1)^nx^k=\sum\limits_{q=0}^{n}\binom{n}{q}m^{n-q}\frac{A_{q}(x)}{(1-x)^{q+1}}$?

Tags: polynomials, summation, infinity

If
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)^nx^k=\frac{A_{n}(x)}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$$
so
$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}(m+k+1)^nx^k=\sum\limits_{q=0}^{n}\binom{n}{q}m^{n-q}\frac{A_{q}(x)}{(1-x)^{q+1}}$$
How can we prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (m+(k+1))^n x^k
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q}(k+1)^q m^{n-q} x^k\\
&= \sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q}m^{n-q}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)^q x^k \\
&= \sum_{q=0}^n \binom{n}{q}m^{n-q}\frac{A_q(x)}{(1-x)^{q+1}} \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may observe that, by the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement),
$$
(m+k+1)^n=\sum\limits_{q=0}^{n}\binom{n}{q}m^{n-q}(k+1)^q.
$$